# getting errors in pom.xml file and how to create settings.xml in maven with out proxy

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

[image]

actually i removed all the .m2/repository folder files and try to fix the issue . but now maven clean install showing errors as you can see in cmd.

i just created a new maven project and it wont let me create one..

please help on this really i tried every possible solutions from internet no luck.

one questions - how to clean all the maven or .m2 folder and start up fresh please advice.[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your command prompt error, you need to setup at least one goal in your pom.xml. For example

```
<goals>
    <goal>java</goal>
 </goals>
```

My suggestions are

1. No need to delete .m2 folder
2. Read maven life cycle [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)
3. If you doubt your project is wrong,then just delete your project from eclipse workspace and create new maven project again
4. Write pom.xml yourself,do not copy the other people pom.xml if you don't understand what they wrote in their pom.xml